# Loading Lodash in HTML via Script Returns Error

Tags: javascript, firefox, lodash

I'm pretty new to html, javascript and stuff, so I hope you can help me.

I would like to use Lodash, and I therefore do the following in my HTML-file:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.17.15-npm/lodash.js"></script>
```

In Firefox (version 78.0.2 (64-bit)) under Ubuntu 20.04, this results in the following error in the Firefox-console:

> The resource from
> “https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.17.15-npm/lodash.js”
> was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, GitHub pages are not made to be used for this purpose. If you analyze the request response, you can see that the response is of type "text/plain" but it should be "application/javascript". So you have a few possible solutions. Either host the script file yourself on your web server or use a CDN (Content Delivery Network) service. If you want to use the latter, do the following.

Replace:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.17.15-npm/lodash.js
```

to:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js
```